# drop column based on a string condition

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

How can I delete a dataframe column based on a certain string in its name?

Example:

```
           house1    house2    chair1  chair2
index
  1         foo       lee       sam      han
  2         fowler    smith     had      sid
  3         cle       meg       mag      mog
```

I want to drop the columns that contain 'chair' in the string.
How can this be done in an efficient way?
Thanks.

Comment: This is a fun question! So many alternatives... +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
df.drop([col for col in df.columns if 'chair' in col],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: cannot decide which one I like the most @bernie

Comment: @Al_Iskander: If you're not using a regex-based solution you're going to have better performance but I think the minute difference in performance is not worth haggling over. At any rate mine was the first answer ;-)

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE2:**

```
In [315]: df
Out[315]:
   3M110%  3M80% 6M90% 6M95% 1N90% 2M110% 3M95%
1     foo    lee   sam   han   aaa    aaa   fff
2  fowler  smith   had   sid   aaa    aaa   fff
3     cle    meg   mag   mog   aaa    aaa   fff

In [316]: df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('90|110')]
Out[316]:
   3M80% 6M95% 3M95%
1    lee   han   fff
2  smith   sid   fff
3    meg   mog   fff
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [40]: df
Out[40]:
   house1 house2 chair1 chair2 door1 window1 floor1
1     foo    lee    sam    han   aaa     aaa    fff
2  fowler  smith    had    sid   aaa     aaa    fff
3     cle    meg    mag    mog   aaa     aaa    fff

In [41]: df.filter(regex='^(?!(chair|door|window).*?)')
Out[41]:
   house1 house2 floor1
1     foo    lee    fff
2  fowler  smith    fff
3     cle    meg    fff
```

**Original answer:**

here a few alternatives:

```
In [37]: df.drop(df.filter(like='chair').columns, 1)
Out[37]:
   house1 house2
1     foo    lee
2  fowler  smith
3     cle    meg

In [38]: df.filter(regex='^(?!chair.*)')
Out[38]:
   house1 house2
1     foo    lee
2  fowler  smith
3     cle    meg
```

Comment: @MaxU, can the first version also be used for multiple different strings in one line?

Comment: @Al_Iskander, what do you mean saying `multiple different strings in one line`? Could you post a short example?

Comment: I mean if I have more columns with different names and besides 'chair' I would also like to drop columns that contain 'door' or 'window' (or whatever) in the name.

Comment: @Al_Iskander, frankly speaking, i do prefer the second option, using `regex` - please see UPDATE

Comment: strangely this regex solution does not work if the partial string is a number, i.e. I have columns names such as 3M110%, 3M80%, 6M90%, 6M95% etc. and when I use regex='^(?!(110|90).*?)' it does not work.

Comment: @Al_Iskander, try this one: `df.filter(regex=r'^\d\w(?!(110|90).*?)')`

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.match(r'chair')], axis=1)
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

**MaxU method 2**

[image]

Comment: I did it slightly differently... +1

Comment: @bernie I bet you your way is quicker.  checking.

Comment: Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 3):

One more alternative:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'house1':['foo','fowler','cle'],
                   'house2':['lee','smith','meg'],
                   'chair1':['sam','had','mag'],
                   'chair2':['han','sid','mog']})

mask = ['chair' not in x for x in df]

df = df[df.columns[mask]]
```

Comment: I agree, some of the other solutions never would have occurred to me but are nonetheless very effective!