# How to drop columns based on column name python pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, string-formatting

I would like to drop every column that ends in a 'y' in my data frame. For some reason, the data I have has each column listed twice, with the only thing different being the column name, like so:

```
d = {'Team': ['1', '2', '3'], 'Team_y': ['1', '2', '3'], 'Color' : ['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'Color_y' : ['red', 'green', 'blue']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    Team    Team_y  Color   Color_y
0    1        1      red     red
1    2        2     green   green
2    3        3      blue    blue
```

I know it's some sort of string formatting. I tried indexing the last letter using [-1] but couldn't quite get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

in addition to @David's answer, you could use pandas [str endswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) to exclude columns ending with '_y':

```
df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.endswith('_y')]

  Team  Color
0   1   red
1   2   green
2   3   blue
```

the ~(tilde) sign serves as negation

The abstractions with [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) [select_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select_columns.select_columns) might be helpful:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd

df.select_columns('*y', invert = True)

  Team  Color
0    1    red
1    2  green
2    3   blue
```

Answer (score 5):

[drop column based on a string condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383886/drop-column-based-on-a-string-condition)

```
df.drop([col for col in df.columns if '_y' in col],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Better yet, if it must be specific to ending with it, then:

```
df.drop([col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('_y')],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a filter by regular expression

```
df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='_y')))]
```